# weirdd mouse problem

Tags: mouse

i am facing some weird problems. it all started after i unplugged  power cable without shutting down the computer.

Currently mouse is not working at all. its not even getting power. However if i connect the mouse to a front usb port, it  gets power but nothing  happens,   not working.

i tried another mouse on the same rear usb port and its working **almost** **fine**.
whats  with this dual behavior? bad mouse(first one)? or did i corrupt my system file?

**Note**
*Almost fine* - cause, sometimes 1 click resulting in 2 clicks.

*keyboard*- same as  mouse. sometimes 1 keypress = 2/3 press.

Edit-

keyboard- shift button dont work sometimes. selected texts get copied without clicking copy.

speaker - only beep like sound.

Comment: A loss of power and not a proper shutdown can certainly cause problems.

Comment: Oky. So should i reinstall the os?

Comment: Many will tell you to spend hours and a lot of effort to fix it. Myself I would save all the personal files and re install quick simple and fixes everything.

Comment: Oky thanks for the suggestion. will do it i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall is the fastest way to fix this and any other hidden problem that may come up later.